# Light-weight alternative to MVC 3 for Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I simply need to iterate through data in a loop and pass some strings through a ViewBag type collection. MVC 3 does the job but in many cases I find it too complex for my needs. Is there anything closer to the Rails View for Asp.net? (I know about Spark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) which is a lightweight version of ASP.NET MVC. It actually represents only the V(iew) part of MVC.

Comment: Interesting. So, you can pretty much do everything that .net provides in its libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use razor without MVC 3.  However, I believe that how light, heavy or complex your MVC 3 code is, depends on the developer, as MVC 3 gives you much more control than Web Forms.  if you follow best practices, I would expect an MVC 3 app to be much lighter weight than an equivalent web forms app unless the app is just one or two pages. There is a learning curve but I think that MVC 3, Razor and the Entity Framework are well worth investing the time in learning them.